# Is it possible to use PyQt 5.12 with Python 3.10?

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to run my PyQt program with Python 3.10 and PyQt 5.12. I am using PyQt 5.12 because this is the most recent version available on Anaconda, unfortunately.

I get an error when I try to take the bitwise-or of two ItemFlags. The following test program demonstrates this.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR
from PyQt5.Qt import PYQT_VERSION_STR

print("Python version: {}".format(sys.version))
print("Qt version: {}".format(QT_VERSION_STR))
print("PyQt version: {}".format(PYQT_VERSION_STR))
print()

a = Qt.NoItemFlags | Qt.ItemIsEnabled
b = Qt.ItemIsTristate | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable

print(a|b)
```

It gives the following exception.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kenter/prog/py/argos/development/int_coercion.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(a|b)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'ItemFlags' and 'ItemFlags'
```

When I run it with Python 3.9 and PyQt 5.12 it works fine. It also works fine when I run it with Python 3.10 and PyQt 5.15. This suggests that something was deprecated in Python 3.10 and this was corrected for in PyQt somewhere between versions 5.12 and 5.15.

I get different errors that seem to indicate the same, al related to implicit conversion to integers.

Can anybode please give some insight here? Is it possible to run PyQt 5.12 with Python 3.10 at all?

Comment: This is something you will just have to accept when using three year old software. Nothing stays bug-free forever. What version of `sip` are you using (`from PyQt5 import sip; print(sip.SIP_VERSION_STR`))? Presumably, it will be v4, which is no longer supported. As a work-around, you can simply convert the flags to `int` before doing bitwise operations: i.e. `Qt.ItemFlags(int(a) | int(b))`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can try entering the Itemflage in an integers. try like this  `a = int(Qt.NoItemFlags) | (Qt.ItemIsEnabled)`, and the same thing for b. maybe it works